# Sending all contacts *with number* via Bluetooth

Tags: contacts, sync, bluetooth

I would like to transfer all my contacts to a different phone from my Android 2.2 device. In my phonebook I disabled showing contacts without numbers. When I choose sending via Bluetooth however all contacts show up, thousands of them without number. I would like to send only those that contain number. I have the option "select all" but this includes and sends all contacts. How could I send only the ones with numbers?

Answer (score 1):

I am also a android phone user. To my knowledge it is not possible. when you import all your conatacts it dumbs everything into a single *.vcf file where with only this file you can export it to an other phone, it does not allow users to select their individual contacts to do so as you have mentioned. The only way is to delete it manually by choosing the contacts individually.

Comment: thanks. i'll wait a bit more to see if someone knows a trick. maybe there is an app for it.. :-)